gtk-rs application executes but sometimes fails to show the window
I built a minimal application using gtk-rs with composite templates following this tutorial
I can compile and execute the application successfully, but sometimes it fails to show the window. If I try to debug the application, it always works as expected. But if I run the application without the debugger attached, it only works 1/3 of the times randomly.
This problem only happens with composite templates because this problem doesn't happen when I use the builder pattern.
I'm using Windows 10 Version 22H2 and GTK Version 4.14.2.
Any clues?
main.rs
mod window;

use std::env;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{gio, glib, Application};
use window::Window;

const APP_ID: &str = "myproject.hello_world";

fn main() -> glib::ExitCode {
    gio::resources_register_include!("todo_1.gresource")
        .expect("Failed to register resource s .");

    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id(APP_ID)
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(build_ui);

    app.run()
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let window = Window::new(app);
    window.present();
}

build.rs
fn main() {
  glib_build_tools::compile_resources(
      &["src/resources"],
      "src/resources/resources.gresource.xml",
      "todo_1.gresource",
  );

window/mod.rs
mod imp;

use glib::Object;
use gtk::{gio, glib, Application};

glib::wrapper! {
    pub struct Window(ObjectSubclass<imp::MainWindow>)
        @extends gtk::ApplicationWindow, gtk::Window, gtk::Widget,
        @implements gio::ActionGroup, gio::ActionMap, gtk::Accessible, gtk::Buildable,
                    gtk::ConstraintTarget, gtk::Native, gtk::Root, gtk::ShortcutManager;
}

impl Window {
    pub fn new(app: &Application) -> Self {
        Object::builder().property("application", app).build()
    }
}

window/imp.rs
use glib::subclass::InitializingObject;
use gtk::subclass::prelude::*;
use gtk::{glib, CompositeTemplate};

#[derive(CompositeTemplate, Default)]
#[template(resource = "/MyProject/main_window.ui")]
pub struct MainWindow {

}

#[glib::object_subclass]
impl ObjectSubclass for MainWindow {
    const NAME: &'static str = "MainWindow";
    type Type = super::Window;
    type ParentType = gtk::ApplicationWindow;

    fn class_init(klass: &mut Self::Class) {
        klass.bind_template();
    }

    fn instance_init(obj: &InitializingObject<Self>) {
        obj.init_template();
    }
}

impl ObjectImpl for MainWindow {
    fn constructed(&self) {
        self.parent_constructed();
    }
}

// Trait shared by all widgets
impl WidgetImpl for MainWindow {}

// Trait shared by all windows
impl WindowImpl for MainWindow {}

// Trait shared by all application windows
impl ApplicationWindowImpl for MainWindow {}

resources/main_window.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <template class="MainWindow" parent="GtkApplicationWindow">
    <property name="width-request">360</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">To-Do</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="margin-top">12</property>
        <property name="margin-bottom">12</property>
        <property name="margin-start">12</property>
        <property name="margin-end">12</property>
        <property name="spacing">6</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="entry">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hello World!</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>

resources/resources.gresource.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/MyProject/">
    <file compressed="true" preprocess="xml-stripblanks">main_window.ui</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>


Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "my_app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.9", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_14"] }

[build-dependencies]
glib-build-tools = "0.20"

